# Using the map() function within a class

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to get the `map()` function to work within a class but have had trouble because I'm not sure if I should be passing self into it. If so, I'm unsure how to make `self` into a list to go with my other iterables. Here is my code so far:

```
from itertools import repeat

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [1, 4, 8]
        self.empty_list = []
        map(self.fxn, repeat(self, len(self.nums)), self.nums)
        print(self.empty_list)

    def fxn(self, num):
        self.empty_list.append(num ** num)

instance = test()
```

Even after trying to append to the empty list, the list still seems to be blank, what am I doing wrong in that example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` doesn't mutate its argument. It returns a new iterable.

```
self.nums = list(map(...))
```

`test.fxn` is a function of two arguments: `self` and `num`. `self.fxn` is a *bound method* of one argument: `num`. Since you're just repeatedly applying it on `self`, you can bind it and save yourself the extra argument.

```
self.nums = list(map(self.fxn, self.nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `map(self.fxn, repeat(self, len(self.nums)), self.nums)` to `self.empty_list=list(map(self.fxn,self.nums))` which is equivalent to `self.empty_list=list(map(lambda x: self.fxn(x),self.nums))` and `self.empty_list=[self.fxn(i) for i in self.nums]` and remember to change `fxn()` from `self.empty_list.append(num ** num)` to `return num ** num` (and since it is `list(map(...))`-`list` it will be a list), so try the below:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [1, 4, 8]
        self.empty_list=list(map(self.fxn,self.nums))
        print(self.empty_list)

    def fxn(self, num):
        return num ** num

instance = test()
```

Output:

```
[1, 256, 16777216]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.